# Drag and Drop Divs and compare values

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have four divs with custom Attributes like:

```
<div marker="A">A1</div>
<div marker="A">A2</div>
<div marker="B">A3</div>
<div marker="B">A4</div>
```

Now I would like to use jquery to make each div drag- and drop-able.
Now when a user drags e.g. div A1 on div A2 (vice-verca would alos be possible), it shall compare the marker attribute and if the marker happens to be the same, I want an alert to inform the user about this.

How would I achieve that ? Can I use jquery-only or do I need a plugin for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

***Updated with live demo!***

Here, as you can see for yourself, using the draggable() and droppable() methods of jQuery UI, it is easy to achieve what you want... You can see the demo here:

http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/dragging-and-dropping.html

Comment: I know those pages and have already read that. If you could read, then you would have had a chance to actually help answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Include jquery ui sortable library...

```
$("div").sortable({
    opacity: 0.6,
    revert: true,
    cursor: 'move',
    update: updateList
});

function updateList() {
    var list = $("div").sortable('toArray').toString();
}
```

`var list` will contain the sorted list of the divs... you will have to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Its a working example :) You will have to figure out how to fit it with your code... give unique ids to your divs, preferably numbers so that you can get a proper feedback from the $("div").sortable('toArray').toString();